# SQL substring code

Tags: mysql, t-sql, char, find, substring

I've got two questions
Given a column called URL (in a links table) that contains examples of url's.

Things like http://facebook.com/hello i need to extract everything till the first / so http://facebook.com 
or 
https://www.cnn.com/video/data/2.0/video/tech/2014/10/30/pkg-future-of-travel-jet-engine-leap-plane.cnn.html the output would be https://cnn.com

This is what I have but i'm not sure if its accurate logic.

```
select distinct SUBSTRING (url,0,(CHARINDEX('/'), URL,0)) 
from links
```

Also I need a MYSQL version. Which i'm not entirely sure is what I've got. 
Please advise. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select substr(url, 1, locate('/', url, (locate('//', url)+3))-1) from ...

For example this:

select substr('abc://bott.com/xxxx', 1, locate('/', 'abc://bott.com/xxxx', (locate('//', 'abc://bott.com/xxxx')+3))-1)

returns this:

abc://bott.com

The 'distinct' will cause you to get only one of any result (no matches).

Comment: Yes, it will skip over that and look for the first '/' after it.

Comment: sorry would i be replacing 'abc://bott.com/xxxx' with the column name?

Comment: Use the first line of the answer and add your from and where clauses to the line. - your column is named "url" right?

Comment: yes so it would be `select substr(URL, 1, locate('/', URL, (locate('//', URL)+3))-1) from tableName`

Answer (score 1):

You looking for this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('http://facebook.com/hello', '/', 3);

=> "http://facebook.com"
```

Comment: firstly its a she. but secondly the url is different for each line in the table, facebook is just an example. I need to use / as a cut off point to find what i need.

Comment: Well its partially correct how about `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.facebook.com/hello', '/', 3);` ? i.e. if the URL does not have `http/s` and a `www` instead ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty the command above will work for all the URL types

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it assuming that you may have `http://` or `https://` or just `www`
The idea is to first replace `//` with a different character say `||` and then use the `substring_index` to parse the string till the first occurrence of `/` and finally replace `||` with `//`

Here are some examples

```
mysql> select replace(substring_index(replace('http://facebook.com/hello','//','||'),'/',1),'||','//') as url;
+---------------------+
| url                 |
+---------------------+
| http://facebook.com |
+---------------------+


mysql> select replace(substring_index(replace('www.facebook.com/hello','//','||'),'/',1),'||','//') as url;
+------------------+
| url              |
+------------------+
| www.facebook.com |
+------------------+



mysql> select replace(substring_index(replace('http://www.facebook.com/hello/a/b/c','//','||'),'/',1),'||','//') as url;
+-------------------------+
| url                     |
+-------------------------+
| http://www.facebook.com |
+-------------------------+

mysql> select replace(substring_index(replace('http://facebook.com/hello/a/b/c','//','||'),'/',1),'||','//') as url;
+---------------------+
| url                 |
+---------------------+
| http://facebook.com |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: That looks pretty cool, but i dont' want to replace i simply want to extract. to pull out the root url.

Comment: The replace is just to make the formula work so that it searches `/` from left side since after the first `/` there may be many `/` so we cant look from right to left. So it should give you what you need.The exact url till the first `/` without changing anything before that :-) I have added few more test in the answer.

Comment: and if the link you've got is replaced by a column? should it still work. (if that column has the whole url in it)

Comment: yes in this case it should be as `select replace(substring_index(replace(your_col_name,'//','||'),'/',1),'||','//') as url from table_name;`

Comment: i can use distinct right? select distinct replace(substring_index(replace(URL,'//','||'),'/',1),'||','//') as url from tableName;

Comment: Yes you can but note that `http://facebook.com` and `https://facebook.com` are not same